# How to serve static files to different routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a site using Express, and when I try to use routes more than one level deep, none of my static files get served. For example, here is my code that is working correctly:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/newSite', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/newSite.html') )

app.get('/organizations', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/organizations.html') )

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I wanted to use something like this for the path:

```
app.get('/admin/organizations', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/organizations.html') )
```

I tried messing around with the `app.use` function because I am thinking that is where my issue is, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far. How do I serve static files to any route?

Edit: Here is the relevant html

```
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./public/global.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./public/organizations.css"/>

</head>
<body>

</body>

<script src = "public/jquery.js"> </script>

<script src = "public/organizations.js"> </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `app.use('/public(/*)?', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`. Does that work?

Comment: I tried and it did not work. It stopped serving static files for my 'newSite' page as well after the change.

Comment: could you post a sample html page how you've linked

Comment: Sure, it's there now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's got to do with `relative` path. With `express` it's *safer* to use `absolute` path.

After your route goes one level *deep*, the html file which is send needs to search one level *up* to find the static files. (You can confirm: `../public/global.css` will actually link static files correctly in your route `/admin/organizations`)

Simple fix: use absolute path (notice it starts only with `/`)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/public/global.css"/>
```